# TabControl MFC visual studio 2008 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, tabcontrol

I have never used MFC so far. I'd like to learn how creating a simple tabcontrol in a SDI application. I'am looking for a very beginner guide or a tutorial? Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awh5x2d4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: I've followed that link but even if it's well-compiled when I run it, an "debug assertion fail" appears at this point: ASSERT(pWnd->m_hWnd == NULL);

Comment: Take a look at the various samples in your Visual Studio installation directory. That said, if you don't know how to fix the assert failure you posted above, you're not at the level where you can realistically expect to be able to build an MFC application.

Comment: @Roel: I am not at the right level; I let my work on pause

Answer (score 0):

I've not installed it on this machine, but as far as i remember, there is a wizard alowing you to create a dialog-based TabCtrl-Application. You could get all you ned to know from htere. Also you may find this Link useful:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/tabcontrols/article.php/c5239/Creating-a-CTabCtrl-Application.htm

Please bear in mind that the TabCtrl is just the tabs, not the space they show – this is a window that you have to make visible, so the usual approach is a couple of windows with the same screen location and the tabctrl makes one visible and hides the others by clicking on it.